# Running a 'GC.Collect' fixes my crash, but I don't understand why

Tags: c#, unmanaged, nokia

I have this piece of code (from the Nokia PC connectivity 3.2 example code, in C#):

```
  DAContentAccessDefinitions.CA_FOLDER_INFO folderInfo =
  new DAContentAccessDefinitions.CA_FOLDER_INFO();
  folderInfo.iSize = Marshal.SizeOf(folderInfo); //(32)

  IntPtr bufItem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(folderInfo.iSize);

  //I often get a AccessViolationException on the following line
  Marshal.StructureToPtr(folderInfo, bufItem, true);
```

If I run `GC.Collect()` at the start of this, then I don't get an `AccessViolationException`. But I don't want to slow down this function unless necessary. I've tried putting `GC.Keepalive` in various places, but without success.

`CA_FOLDER_INFO` is defined as:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct CA_FOLDER_INFO
    {
        public int iSize;
        public int iFolderId;
        public int iOptions;
        public string pstrName;
        public string pstrPath;
        public int iSubFolderCount;
        public IntPtr pSubFolders;
        public IntPtr pParent;
    }
```

I don't, in this instance, require either of the strings, and changing their definitions to `IntPtr` seems to make the exception go away.

What is going on here, and what is the correct way to prevent the exception?

Comment: Dont forget to wrap that in a try-finally that calls Marshal.FreeHGlobal when you're done with bufItem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing true to Marshal.StructureToPtr so it attempts to free the two string pointers (which are sometimes invalid). You need to pass false in this instance since you just allocated that memory on the heap. (i.e. there's nothing to free there).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, and is an explanation I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fixed keyword to get a pointer to your original `folderInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that unmanaged resources aren't being released by something. Check to see if anything you're using implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and if so, wrap it in a `using { }` block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Marshal.Sizeof(bufItem) and Marshal.Sizeof(folderInfo) are the same?

And, maybe the fact that you aren't initializing the strings? Since you say you don't get the error when they are IntPtr (which defaults to IntPtr.Zero), I'd try setting them both to empty strings before you try marshaling the buffer item.

**[Edit]**

Maybe you should try pinning the buffer handle, and marshaling that to the structure, rather than vis versa. Something like this:

```
DAContentAccessDefinitions.CA_FOLDER_INFO folderInfo;

GCHandle pinnedHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffItem, GCHandleType.Pinned);
folderInfo = (DAContentAccessDefinitions.CA_FOLDER_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pin.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(DAContentAccessDefinitions.CA_FOLDER_INFO));
pin.Free();

//folderInfo should contain the data from buffItem
```

Comment: Setting the two string fields to "" or String.Empty does not make the AccessViolationException go away...